# grep command with regex not working on gitlab ci

Tags: grep, gitlab-ci

I am running script in my gitlab ci:

```
pre_build:
  stage: get_info
  script:
    - printenv
    - cd ./scripts
    - ./pre_build.sh
```

this script has the following line:

```
todays_date=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
latest=$(curl -i ${artifactory_url} | grep develop | grep -i ${todays_date} | grep ${last_ok_build_number} | grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' | grep -Eo 'href="[^\"]+"')
```

I believe this is failing due to regex in grep, any idea how to run this in GitLab ci?
Above script works perfectly well on my local machine

**EDIT**: Above codes works it was timezone issue

Comment: Since you're not specifying an image in your stage, what image are you using to run your job? GitLab's shared runners use ruby by default, you could try swapping linux distros to see if that made a difference. If you're running a specific distro locally, try the same distro in your CI/CD job image.


A second note - Artifactory returns JSON objects when querying for specific binaries.  Is there a reason to pipe multiple grep commands together to get the info you need instead of using JQ?

Comment: there was timing issue. where i gitlab was running it was on IST where as I am on PDT. 
I had a check if package is empty throw error. 
In short, above code works i just wasted 2 hrs of my life

Comment: Whoops. That'd do it. Another reason to maybe look at JQ to find the most recent good build - you're not reliant on weird timezone race conditions :)

Comment: yeah you are right